# PhantomJs example not working?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Can someone please tell me why the example in below link is not working. I even added the timeout to 12 seconds. Always showing me => console.log("'waitFor()' timeout");

Link: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js

I copied the example but not working. I am trying to run it using 'phantomjs'. Can someone please guide me what could be the possible reasons?

PhantomJS version: 2.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified this script, and now it's working:

```
/**
 * Wait until the test condition is true or a timeout occurs. Useful for waiting
 * on a server response or for a ui change (fadeIn, etc.) to occur.
 *
 * @param testFx javascript condition that evaluates to a boolean,
 * it can be passed in as a string (e.g.: "1 == 1" or "$('#bar').is(':visible')" or
 * as a callback function.
 * @param onReady what to do when testFx condition is fulfilled,
 * it can be passed in as a string (e.g.: "1 == 1" or "$('#bar').is(':visible')" or
 * as a callback function.
 * @param timeOutMillis the max amount of time to wait. If not specified, 3 sec is used.
 */

"use strict";
function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
    var maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 5000, //< Default Max Timout is 3s
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        condition = false,
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if ( (new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition ) {
                // If not time-out yet and condition not yet fulfilled
                condition = (typeof(testFx) === "string" ? eval(testFx) : testFx()); //< defensive code
            } else {
                if(!condition) {
                    // If condition still not fulfilled (timeout but condition is 'false')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' timeout");
                    phantom.exit(1);
                } else {
                    // Condition fulfilled (timeout and/or condition is 'true')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' finished in " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + "ms.");
                    typeof(onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady(); //< Do what it's supposed to do once the condition is fulfilled
                    clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                }
            }
        }, 250); //< repeat check every 250ms
};


function click(sel){var event=document.createEvent('MouseEvents');event.initMouseEvent('click',1,1,window,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,null);document.querySelector(sel).dispatchEvent(event);}
var page = require('webpage').create();

// Open Twitter on 'sencha' profile and, onPageLoad, do...
page.open("https://twitter.com/sencha", function (status) {
    // Check for page load success
    if (status !== "success") {
        console.log("Unable to access network");
    } else {
       page.evaluate(function(click) {click('a[id="signin-link"]');},click)//,click will be available
        // Wait for 'signin-dropdown' to be visible
        waitFor(function() {
            // Check in the page if a specific element is now visible
            return page.evaluate(function() {
                return $("div#signin-dropdown").is(":visible");
            });
        }, function() {
           console.log("The sign-in dialog should be visible now.");
           phantom.exit();
        });
    }
page.render('sencha.png'); 
});
```

Comment: Now we are sending a click, to open the dropdown menu and make it visible.

Comment: *Meta-comment:* Hi Igor, I've noticed that you sometimes delete answers that you haven't received any feedback. Please don't do that. If there is no other better answer, then your answer may actually help future readers. I can also say that some askers actually forget that they asked a question and sometimes will revisit their question at a much later time. I've had answers accepted over a year after I posted them. Please visit [your recently deleted answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/4535610) and look through them to see if you can undelete some of them.